# How to fill part of the graphical figure

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing, fill

So, I have some simple figure (circle, ellipse, rectangle of closed polygon) and I need to fill only part of it.

I mean, I have `GraphicsPath` or similar object (set of points) and now I can simply fill the whole figure with, for example, orange color.

What I need: user enters 25% and I fill only 25% of the figure, starting from some side (top/bottom).

Maybe, it will be nessesary to find some sub-figure or (bad idea, I know) check all the points in on the field and fill them (only those which inside figure) one by one untill their amount will be 1/4 from the area of the figure. But it won't be so fast especially when image is about 5-6000 pixels from one side.

Here's sample what I have now and what I need for 25%. Important: instead of 25% can be any value.

Project: C# .net 3.5 WinForms

**UPD**:
Basic usecase.

1. User draws a figure (circle, ellipse, rectangle, polygon)
2. User enters value from 0 to 100 (percents)
3. I fill figure from bottom to the top until I filled amount of area (!), which is equal to user's value

I'm open for any ideas even without code.

[image: What I have and what I need]

Comment: If you mean you want to fill 25% of the height etc the solution is simple: Just fillPath after doing a graphics.setclip() with  a suitable rectangle. - If you mean not height or width but area, things will get a __lot__ harder. I would still use the same approach but iterate to approach the best appoximation of the rectangle. For this I would write a fast color count routine using lockbits..

Comment: [GraphicsPath.SetMarkers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.setmarkers) + [GraphicsPathIterator.NextSubpath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspathiterator.nextsubpath) -- Or [GraphicsContainer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicscontainer). Or a combination. It depends on what 25% you need to fill: 25% related to the overall Height/Width of the polygon, no problem, 25% of the content, *problem*: you have to calculate the area of the polygon.

Comment: I agree with Taw.  Calculate the width/height of the bounding rectangle for your shape.  Then you're just filling in a normal rectangle (adjusted to the specified percentage) that is being clipped with the GraphicsPath object itself.

Comment: Can you post sample code that produces that example GraphicsPath?

Comment: @Idle_Mind, I just made it in paint). Users will be drawing figures

Comment: @TaW, yes I need to fill 25% of the area( The figure itself will be drawn by user

Comment: To get an approximation of the area, create a Region from the resulting GraphicsPath and then use the technique [in this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4418556/2330053)?

Comment: To fill to a certain percentage, you could scan point by point across the bounding box (from bottom to top as you described) and then find any boxes from the link in my previous comment that contain that point.  You'd add up the width of each box from that row, keeping a running sum until you exceed the desired percentage based on the previous "total area" calculation.  Now you know how many rows are necessary to hit the percentage and can just fill using the method outlined by TaW in the first comment.  I think this will get you "close enough"?

Comment: Untested color counter: `public long CountColor(Bitmap bmp, Color c)
{
    long count = 0;

    PixelFormat fmt = bmp.PixelFormat;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Size.Width, bmp.Size.Height);
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, fmt);
    byte bpp = 4;
    if (fmt == PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb) bpp = 3; // add more formats as needed!
    int size = bmpData.Stride * bmpData.Height;
    byte[] data = new byte[size];

    Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, data, 0, size);`

Comment: `for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Size.Height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Size.Width; x++)
    {
        int index = y * bmpData.Stride + x * bpp;


        if (bpp == 4)
            if (c.B == data[index + 0] && c.G == data[index + 1]
                && c.R == data[index + 2] && c.A == data[index + 3]) count++;

            else if (bpp == 3)
                if (c.B == data[index + 0] && c.G == data[index + 1]
                    && c.R == data[index + 2]) count++;
    }
}
//Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bmpData.Scan0, data.Length);
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
return count;
}`

Comment: It takes 2-4 more lines of code to expand the signature to include/fill up an array of pixel counters for each row of the bitmap, thereby saving multiple runs.. - The rest is simple as well; just tested it with a trackbar to set the percentage for the clipping rectangle. About 100 lines of code for the whole test program.. Doing it sideways would require to switch the loops.